# Apk file not building using androidjs

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

I was learning to build android apps from nodejs using androidjs library.
Official site- https://android-js.github.io/ ,
documentation- https://android-js.github.io/androidjs/
So, I started with sample app provided by its offcial site, source code link- https://github.com/android-js/androidjs/ , install all the necessary packages and follow the procedure provided. But apk file is never built and I got build process exited with code 1 and sign process exited with code 1.
Here is what I got in my console:

```
{ DEBUG: false,
  BUILDER__cwd: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/androidjs-builder',
  PROJECT__cwd: '/home/satnam/AndroidStudioProjects/mywork/story app',
  PROJECT__dist: '/home/satnam/AndroidStudioProjects/mywork/story app/dist',
  PROJECT__DIST__name: 'dist',
  platform: 'linux',
  force_replace: true }
app core copied !
Core Modules Copied !
copying user app done.
User data copied
reading  /home/satnam/AndroidStudioProjects/mywork/story app/dist/app-debug/AndroidManifest.xml
User assets cleared
package name com.androidjs.mypkg
{ '$': { 'android:name': 'android.permission.INTERNET' } }
{ '$':
   { 'android:name': 'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' } }
{ '$':
   { 'android:name': 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' } }
android.webkit.PermissionRequest
Done!
AndroidManifest updated!
changing app name /home/satnam/AndroidStudioProjects/mywork/story app/dist/app-debug/res/values/strings.xml
{ _: 'myapp', '$': { name: 'app_name' } }
App Name updated!
Icon updated!
Building...
(node:5860) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
I: Using Apktool 2.4.0

I: Checking whether sources has changed...

I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...

I: Checking whether resources has changed...

I: Building resources...

build process exited with code 1
Build finished!
Sign apk
stderr: provided apk path or file '/home/satnam/AndroidStudioProjects/mywork/story app/dist/app.apk' does not exist

stderr: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provided apk path or file '/home/satnam/AndroidStudioProjects/mywork/story app/dist/app.apk' does not exist
stderr:
        at at.favre.tools.apksigner.ui.FileArgParser.parseAndSortUniqueFilesNonRecursive(FileArgParser.java:38)
        at at.favre.tools.apksigner.SignTool.execute(SignTool.java:63)
stderr:
        at at.favre.tools.apksigner.SignTool.mainExecute(SignTool.java:48)
        at at.favre.tools.apksigner.SignTool.main(SignTool.java:36)

stderr:
Cmd history for debugging purpose:
-----------------------
sign process exited with code 1
```

I have tried with my own nodejs app too, but it's giving me same error.
I don't know what to do, I need help building this. I have to submit android project in college but I have a great interest in nodejs, so I want to build android app from node app. In addition, if you know any other method to build android app from node app you can suggest me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, did you downgrade and test ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that they are currently having an [issue](https://github.com/android-js/androidjs/issues/28)

> Maybe there are some issues in `androidjs-builder@1.0.7`.
>
> We'll fix this
>   issues ASAP, **For now you can downgrade to older version 1.0.6** follow
>   these steps:
>
> `npm uninstall -g androidjs-builder`
>
> `npm install -g androidjs-builder@1.0.6`

---

**I have just tested their *Getting Started Example* and it has worked** (`androidjs-builder@1.0.6`)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed and also added some new features to the newer version of Android JS 2.0.0.

So let's check it out version 2.0

website: https://android-js.github.io

docs: https://android-js.github.io/docs

repo: https://github.com/android-js/androidjs

npm: https://npmjs.com/package/androidjs